# SPRING DATA JPA- GET LIST OF OBJECT BY DISCTINCT AND ORDER BY PROPERTY

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have some Website_Package_mapping that contains Website and Package Object.
i want List by following Criteria.

1> Unique webDetail;
2> Lowest Price;

```
public class WebsitePackageMapping implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private int userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "website_id")
    private WebDetail webDetail;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "package_id")
    private WebPackage webPackage;

    private BigDecimal price;
    getter setter...........
}
public class WebDetail implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String url, name, title, type, image, description, shortDescription;
    private int domainAuthority, traffic, spamScore;
    boolean buyer, seller;
    private byte[] screenshot;
getter setter....
}
```

suppose my table have following data (image attached)i need lowest price and unique website_id. can any one help me out to write query or method for this. i am using JPA_REPOSITORY. i try `public List<WebsitePackageMapping> findDistinctWebdetailOrderByPrice();` but it didn't work.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `asc` on the method-name, that's what you need:

```
findDistinctWebdetailOrderByPriceAsc();
```